# Cosmos DB order by descending tokenvalue

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have created a helper method to retrieve rows in descending order with continuationtoken using Cosmos DB C# Library. However it returns no rows when I try order by descending. The query works without orderby or orderbydescending. Please let me know what I need to correct to retrieve rows in correct order.

```
  public static async Task<(IEnumerable<T> resultRows, string responseContinuation)> GetIAlltemsAsyncOrderByCount(Expression<Func<T,bool>> predicate, Expression<Func<T,object>> orderby,bool descending, int MaxItemCountPerQuery,string continuationToken="")
    {
        var uri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId);

        var feedOptions = new FeedOptions
        {
            MaxItemCount = MaxItemCountPerQuery
        };

        string responseContinuation = "";

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(continuationToken))
        {
            feedOptions.RequestContinuation = continuationToken;
            responseContinuation = continuationToken;
        }

        var resultRows = new List<T>();

            using (var query = descending ? client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(uri, feedOptions).Where(predicate).OrderByDescending(orderby).AsDocumentQuery() : client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(uri, feedOptions).Where(predicate).OrderBy(orderby
                ).AsDocumentQuery())
            {


                if (query.HasMoreResults)
                {
                    var result = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<T>();

                    responseContinuation = result.ResponseContinuation;

                    resultRows.AddRange(result);


                    /* process result */

                }
            }

            return (resultRows, responseContinuation);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I checked this issue on my side and found I could encounter the similar issue. Then I used Fiddler to capture the network traces as follows:

[image]

As [indexing-policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/indexing-policies#changes-to-the-indexing-policy-specification) states as follows:

> Index kind: Hash (equality queries), Range (equality, range or **ORDER BY queries**), or Spatial (spatial queries) .
>
> Range supports efficient equality queries, range queries (using >, <, >=, <=, !=), and ORDER BY queries. **ORDER By queries by default also require maximum index precision (-1)**. The data type can be String or Number.

I log into portal to choose my Cosmos DB account and modify the Indexing Policy under Scale & Settings of my collection as follows:

[image]

Based on the above changes, I could order by the string data type.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. Is there any web page links that shows how to create indexes? According to your information I would need index of datetime column.

Comment: By default, all Azure Cosmos DB data is indexed. You could use [Microsoft Azure Cosmos DB Client Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB/) to create the collection with the specific index policies or update the index policies for the existing collection. Or you could just modify the index policies for the existing collection on Azure Portal. You need specific the index path and index type for the specific data type, details you could follow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/indexing-policies).

Comment: Per my understanding, your datetime column would be stored as string data, the above modified policies based on the default policies could meet your requirement.

Comment: Thank you for the help. In my case, nothing came indexed.

Comment: I have talked to cosmosDB engineer. He and I have done a number of things to fix but while it works now for date attributes, it did not work against custom integer field. I use c# SDK and I was told to keep on the look out for continuation token and keep waiting for valid set of data but turned out to be extremely counter productive. All in all, I think there is a bug and I don't believe MS is willing to fix it at this moment.